# SQL ORDER BY in IN subquery returns no results

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-order-by, h2, sql-in

I am using SQL (H2 database engine ver 1.4.181) and am trying to sum the top 5 points that a student has. The RESULTS table includes the studentID, eventID and points. Each student can only be entered in an event once. The following subquery is what I am trying to use to do this for the student with and id of 5.

```
SELECT SUM(points) FROM RESULTS 
    WHERE eventID IN
        (SELECT TOP 5 eventID FROM RESULTS 
             WHERE studentID = 5 ORDER BY points DESC) 
        AND studentID = 5;
```

However, this query is returning null. I have found that, if the `ORDER BY points DESC` is removed, then the rest of the query works. Does anyone know how to incorporate the ORDER BY, or why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: What database system are you using, and what version of it?

Comment: Does the `point` column have nulls?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in H2. You could use a join. Complete test case:

```
create table results(eventId int, points int, studentId int);
insert into results values(1, 10, 1), (2, 20, 1), (3, 5, 1);
insert into results values(1, 10, 2), (2, 20, 2), (3, 5, 2);
insert into results values(1, 10, 3), (2, 20, 3), (3, 5, 3);

SELECT SUM(r.points) FROM RESULTS r,
(SELECT eventID FROM RESULTS 
  WHERE studentID = 2 
  ORDER BY points DESC
  LIMIT 2 ) r2
WHERE r2.eventID = r.eventId
AND studentID = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

try using join, you can use  sql like this belw

```
select sum(x.points) from 
(select points , event_id  from RESULTS) X 
(select eventID from 
(SELECT  eventID, row_number() over (partition by points ORDER BY points DESC ) tops FROM RESULTS )  X
where tops<6 ) Y 
where X.eventID=y.eventID 
and X.studentID = 5;
```

Comment: I'm getting:
`Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT SUM(X.POINTS) FROM 
(SELECT POINTS , EVENTID  FROM RESULTS) X 
([*]SELECT EVENTID FROM 
(SELECT  EVENTID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY POINTS ORDER BY POINTS DESC ) TOPS FROM RESULTS )  X 
WHERE TOPS<6 ) Y 
WHERE X.EVENTID=Y.EVENTID 
AND X.STUDENTID = 32179 "; [42000-181] 42000/42000`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't need an IN query at all. The following worked perfectly:

```
SELECT SUM(points) FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 5 points FROM RESULTS 
        WHERE studentID = 5
        ORDER BY points DESC);
```